# Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration for JPA Repository

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on a springboot project using JPA repository for PostGres sql,

My pom.xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.upload</groupId>
    <artifactId>FileUpload</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FileUpload</name>
    <description>Exccel File Upload for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and my JPA Repository

```
       package com.upload.FileUpload.service;
    
    import com.upload.FileUpload.entity.FileEntries;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
    public interface UploadRepository extends JpaRepository<FileEntries,Integer> {
    
    }
```

My Service Impl class is

```
package com.upload.FileUpload.service;

    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    
    import javax.transaction.Transactional;
    
             @Service
            @AllArgsConstructor
            @Slf4j
            @Transactional
            public class UploadServiceImpl implements UploadService {
            
                private UploadRepository uploadRepository;
        
        }
```

My Mainapplication.class

```
package com.upload.FileUpload;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class FileUploadApplication {



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FileUploadApplication.class, args);
}
```

My application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.sql-script-encoding=UTF-8
```

I am getting the below error

> ---
>
> ```
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
> ***************************
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in com.upload.FileUpload.service.UploadServiceImpl required a bean of
> ```
>
> type 'com.upload.FileUpload.service.UploadRepository' that could not
> be found.
>
> ```
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.upload.FileUpload.service.UploadRepository' in your
> ```
>
> configuration.

Can someone tell me what is the issue here

Answer (score 0):

you have to add `@Autowired` Annotation on your `UploadRepository`  Declaration

```
package com.upload.FileUpload.service;

    import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

             @Service
            @AllArgsConstructor
            @Slf4j
            @Transactional
            public class UploadServiceImpl implements UploadService {

                @Autowired
                private UploadRepository uploadRepository;

        }
```